# Display Record after 5 mins from the current timestamp - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-moment

I wanted the display the records only after 5 mins from the current timestamp.

Below is my HTML Code,

```
 <div *ngFor="let bookings of newBookings" class="card  mb-4">

        <div *ngIf="isTimestampAfterCurrent(bookings?.currentTimeStamp)"   class="card-body">
....
</div>
</div>
```

In my component.ts

```
 isTimestampAfterCurrent(timestamp: string): boolean {
    if (!timestamp) {
      // If timestamp is not available, display the booking
      return true;
    }
  
    const currentTimestamp = moment(); // Get the current timestamp
    const bookingTimestamp = moment(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    console.log(bookingTimestamp);
    return bookingTimestamp.isAfter(currentTimestamp.add(5, 'minutes'));
  }
```

Note: Format of the currentTimeStamp = 2023-06-25 02:29:49

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the last line of your code. The `.add()` function only mutates the `Moment` object but doesn't seem to return it.

Here is a working example:

```js
const currentMoment = moment('2023-01-01'); // Current Moment
const futureMoment4 = moment('2023-01-01').add(4, 'minutes'); // Moment 4 Minutes from Now
const futureMoment10 = moment('2023-01-01').add(10, 'minutes'); // Moment 10 Minutes from Now

currentMoment.add(5, 'm');

const isFutureMoment4Ahead = futureMoment4.isAfter(currentMoment);
const isFutureMoment10Ahead = futureMoment10.isAfter(currentMoment);

if (isFutureMoment4Ahead) {
  console.log("futureMoment4 is more than 5 minutes ahead of currentMoment");
} else {
  console.log("futureMoment4 is not more than 5 minutes ahead of currentMoment"); // this is the output
}

if (isFutureMoment10Ahead) {
  console.log("futureMoment10 is more than 5 minutes ahead of currentMoment"); // this is the output
} else {
  console.log("futureMoment10 is not more than 5 minutes ahead of currentMoment");
}
```